# attachment is not working in adobe reader

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, acrobat-sdk

I have a fillable pdf with few text boxes in it and a save button. When the user fills the form and clicks the save button using `Acrobat Pro` I am able to save the data as an attachment in pdf, But the problem is When the user opens the pdf using `Adobe Reader` and try to do the same thing as above I am getting following error.

[image]

I have been searching for a week but no luck. Is there any way to make `createDataObject()` function work in `Adobe Reader`? or Is there any other way we can embed data into pdf?

**Note:** I am using `Acrobat Javascript` for this functionality. And I am using `Adobe Reader version 11` and `Acrobat pro version 11` and my OS is `Windows`.

Answer (score 2):

What I have read so far is that getting file attachments working in Adobe Reader requires certain security settings to be enabled. Check out this [Adobe forum post](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4947845). According to it, attaching files from within Adobe Reader is only possible if you have [Adobe Reader Extensions](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/modules.html#c) and allow users with Reader to add attachments.

I've been trying to get attachments working in Adobe Reader with Adobe LiveCycle and Adobe Pro myself, but also no luck so far. If anyone can give any workarounds, I'd be very interested in them myself.

Comment: Yes. There is Adobe live cycle to create certificates. @lischen_

Answer (score 1):

Our workaround is to put a JS file in

```
/c/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Acrobat DC/Acrobat/Javascripts/
```

or where ever.

This file has things like

```
app.PermittedFunction = function(some parameters here)
{
    app.beginPriv();
    Do fancy stuff here
    app.endPriv();
}
app.trustedFunction(app.PermittedFunction)
```

Then we set button or menu Javascript actions as just

```
app.PermittedFunction(Generally pass in at least this so the file is clear)
```

And that should get you around the security errors.